# Problem with attributes method OR send method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This line of code:

```
@instance.attributes.each{|key, value| @instance.send(key) = nil}
```

yields this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '}'
```

I'm having trouble understanding why that is.. When I write something like:

```
@instance.attributes.each{|key, value| puts @instance.send(key)}
```

it behaves as expected, outputting the value of each attribute. Why does it work as a getter but not as a setter in this context? Is there a problem with my syntax?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: BTW, if `@instance` is an `ActiveRecord` instance, you could use `@instance[key] = nil`, see [`ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods#[]=`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)

Comment: I could have sworn that that was the first thing I tried, but right you are. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@instance.send(key)
```

Is calling the getter method. To call the setter method, try:

```
@instance.attributes.each{|key, value| @instance.send("#{key}=", nil)}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. Why is it that I can ordinarily call a setter method without using this syntax? eg `@instance.attribute = nil` rather than `@instance.attribute=(nil)`

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know the precise answer and hesitate to speculate. I suppose some digging through the source code would likely reveal the answer. Or, one of the gurus may swing by and tell us why. Apologies!

Comment: @JoshKestenberg it's called syntactic sugar. The parser detects certain structures and converts them, so you can write `@instance.attribute = nil` to invoke a setter, or `1 + 2` instead of `1.+(2)`.

Comment: @Stefan - Great explanation. Thanks!